# Why does a Foreman export for Upstart run 3 unix processes?

Tags: tomcat, foreman

I am running `foreman export upstart` which generates 3 conf files.

Even if I export with a concurrency value of one, I can see three unix processes being started:

```
$ sudo start tomcat
tomcat start/running

$ initctl list | grep tomcat
tomcat start/running
tomcat-web-1 start/running, process 3966
tomcat-web start/running

$ ps -ax | grep tomcat
 3966 ?        Ss     0:00 su - someUser -c cd /opt/tomcat; export PORT=xxx; export PORT=xxx;  export PATH=xxx;  export JAVA_OPTS=xxx;  export MAVEN_OPTS=xxx; ./webapp-runner.sh >> /var/log/tomcat/web-1.log 2>&1
 3977 ?        S      0:00 -su -c cd /opt/tomcat; ... ./webapp-runner.sh >> /var/log/tomcat/web-1.log 2>&1
 3978 ?        S      0:00 -su -c cd /opt/tomcat; ... ./webapp-runner.sh >> /var/log/tomcat/web-1.log 2>&1
```

Why is that the case? Does it mean that standard app (tomcat) ports (like 8080) won't be released until all 3 processes are killed?

Comment: i am no expert but i think if you stopped the process 3966 via upstart or kill command the other two would stop

Comment: I wish! The ports are locked, a respawn runs and fails due to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my reply to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205314/upstart-script-for-tomcat-respawn-on-ubuntu/15214975#15214975), you are looking at the wrong set of processes that don't represent your Tomcat java webserver. You just need to change to grep java rather than grep tomcat, and you'll see that there's only one process running.